# Installing a .deb package on Arch - Is it possible?

Tags: debian, arch-linux

The problem is simple - I have a .deb package and I want to install it on my Arch Linux. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Note that [.deb files are just archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29#Design) that can be uncompressed on any system. Depending on how complex the installation process is, that might be enough to "install" it.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. Is it a good idea? That depends. You would only really need to do this if the application only exists as a `.deb` package. It is much more likely that you can just grab the upstream source and write a simple [PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pkgbuild) to install it with pacman.

You should also search [the AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR) to ensure that someone hasn't done this already.

Comment: Note, that even if a source package is not provided (or easily accessible), `.deb` files are easily extracted with `libarchive`. And, `makepkg` uses `bsdtar` (which uses `libarchive`) by default to extract sources in a `PKGBUILD`. The result of this dependency chain is that you can easily write `PKGBUILD`s that make use of `.deb` archives as source files. :D

Comment: Maybe link an example PKGBUILD?

Comment: Or if the AUR build fails ...

Answer (score 64):

[dpkg for Arch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dpkg) exists. You should be able to install `.deb` packages on arch, but you should also not use it instead of `pacman`, so just use it for selected few packages.

The default command looks like:

```
# dpkg -i package.deb
```

Comment: Using an alternate package manager, though an option, is not the correct solution. The correct solution is to write a `PKGBUILD` to generate a pacman-native package.

Comment: command not found: dpkg

Comment: Even if it isn't the correct way to do it, it answers the original question... "Is it possible to install a deb package, and how to do it" is answered a lot better by this answer, than simply saying "write a PKGBUILD to generate a native package", since that is not what the user asks...

Comment: Has dpkg been removed? It doesn't exist at the linked to location.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist It's a normal pacman package now, and can be installed using `sudo pacman -S dpkg`. However, after installing it, it warns the user that using it to install debian packages can break their system, so take that as you will.

Comment: the source project is discontinued and has build errors in both the AUR PKGBUILD and when I try to build from source. but there is a debian package from an earlier build so totally agree with @svin83 here.

Comment: And, the link is now broken. Now we use `debtap` from the AUR. https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/debtap

Answer (score 57):

Possible? Yes, but different methods exist on basis of use case.

Assumption: The debian package doesn't have an equivalent package in the Arch (or Arch based Distribution's) official repository.

1. Install [`yay`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/yay/) using `pacman`:

   ```
    sudo pacman -S yay
   ```

*Reason:* yay is an [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers) used to query & install [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) packages. In case the debian package has already been repackaged and published to the AUR by someone else.

2. Install the `package_name` using yay:

   ```
    yay -S package_name
   ```

**note:** replace `package_name` with the name of the debian package as found in the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/). It'll attempt to install the dependencies on it's own using `pacman`.

#### Alternative

Assumption: The Debian package hasn't been repackaged as an Arch package in AUR yet.

1. Install [`debtap`](https://github.com/helixarch/debtap) from AUR using `yay`:

   ```
    yay -S debtap
   ```
2. Create equivalent package using `debtap`:

   ```
    sudo debtap -u
    debtap package_name.deb
   ```
3. Install using `pacman`:

   ```
    sudo pacman -U package_name.pkg
   ```

#### Not the recommended way (possibly dangerous)

*This method attempts to install the package using the debian packaging format on Arch, which is not recommended due to possible danger of corrupting your installation. **If using this method it is recommended to be ready with a rescue disc image of Arch & backup of the user data/space**.*

1. Install [`dpkg`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dpkg/) using `yay`:

   ```
    yay -S dpkg
   ```
2. Install the debian package using `dpkg`:

   ```
    sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
   ```

Comment: `yaourt` is not in the Arch repositories, and `pacman -S yaourt` won't work. It is an *abandoned* AUR package. Rather, you should be explaining how to build an AUR package, and simply *note* that there are AUR helpers like `yaourt` and `yay`.

Comment: At the time of writing it used to be available in the Manjaro Repositories, but as you have mentioned I should update the answer to match the current status

Comment: It may have been available in the Manjaro repositories, but it has never been in the Arch repositories.

Comment: AUR helpers like yay and yaourt should not be run using sudo. These will ask to elevate permission when installing, but build script should be run as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 3):

You can install dpkg by: `yaourt dpkg`.

If you don't have `yaourt`, you can get it from [its AUR page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/yaourt/).

Then just `cd` to where you put it and `dpkg -i package.deb` whatever the package may be

Comment: The current comment on the AUR package for dpkg states it is out of date and "Don't use it instead of Arch's 'pacman'."
Does this mean pacman can now be used to install deb packages?

Comment: @gromain I believe they say that to tell an ignorant user that they shouldn't be using Debian package management in Arch by default -- it should be an exception rather than the rule.

Comment: This package is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

This works for some packages:

```bsh
# You might append this to ~/.bashrc
function debinstall() {
  ar x $1 data.tar.xz
  mkdir /tmp/$1_dir
  tar -C /tmp/$1_dir -xf data.tar.xz
  sudo rsync /tmp/$1_dir /
  rm -f data.tar.xz
  rm -rf /tmp/$1_dir
}
    
# Usage
debinstall draw.io-amd64-13.6.2.deb # Put your package name instead
```