# Can we create Arch Linux packages from Debian packages securely?

Tags: arch-linux, tar, deb

I have made a very simple terminal game:
https://github.com/Souravgoswami/t-hangman

I have also created the Deb file.

We surely can move the source code to /usr/bin/ directory and the word file to /usr/share/t-hangman on any Linux system to get the source code running.

But the problem is that installing dependency (only Ruby) manually, and also moving the source code, changing permissions to 755 and setting root as owner may be confusing to some people.

Can I convert the Debian package into Arch Linux tar.gz package securely so that we can run `pacman -U t-hangman-v3.0.tar.gz` and install it?

**EDIT:**

A stackexchange post suggests using dpkg on Arch Linux - I think that's not a good choice, in fact the uploader of dpkg forbids "The Debian Package Manager. Don't use it instead of Arch's 'pacman'." [AUR Link](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dpkg/)

Comment: Related: [Installing a .deb package on Arch - Is it possible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83540/installing-a-deb-package-on-arch-is-it-possible)

Comment: possible, but I don't know any existing tools that can do this.

Comment: Yes, the question is similar. But the answers are mostly about a hack to install deb files with dpkg, except debtrap. One more question, will debtrap be secure enough for converting big .deb GUI game installer (with SDL, Ruby, Simple2D, Ruby2D, GCC, make, etc. dependency)  as well?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried debtap. After successfully generating the tar.gz file, I went to install it with `pacman -U <...>`. It says:

`loading packages...

error: invalid package version in t-hangman-3.0-any.pkg.tar.xz

error: 't-hangman-3.0-any.pkg.tar.xz': invalid or corrupted package`